# Morphism risen from pushback $\circ$ push forward of a locally free sheaf.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a morphism between two varieties,

$f:X\rightarrow Y$.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally free sheaf on $X$. Also assume $f_*\mathcal{F}$ is locally free on $Y$.

Then we have a nature surjection of locally sheaves :

$\phi:f^*f_*(\mathcal{F})\rightarrow\mathcal{F}$

Let $Z=\mathbb{P}(f_*\mathcal{F})$ be the projective bundle over $Y$ of $f_*\mathcal{F}$ over $Y$.

It claims that the natural surjection $\phi$ gives a map:

$g:X\rightarrow Z$.

I don't see how the last map $g$ risen from $\phi$.

Could anyone kindly point out for me, or what I am missing in the statement?

Comment: There is no such natural map unless $\mathcal{F}$ is of rank one. In your situation, you need to take the Grassmannian of quotients of rank $\mathcal{F}$, not $\mathbb{P}(f_*\mathcal{F})$.

Comment: I think,the surjection $\phi$ exists when $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf.    But the map $g$ may require more conditions, say $\mathcal{F}$ is a line bundle.

Comment: @Shuhang: The natural map $\phi$ is not generally a surjection; assuming that it is surjective is an extra assumption (necessary for obtaining $g$).  E.g. think about the case when $Y = $ Spec $k$ is a point; then $\varphi$ is surjective if and only if $\mathcal F$ is generated by global sections.

Comment: @tracing  Yes, you are right, thanks for pointing out. So, then , what possible conditions make $\phi$ be surjective ?   And If $\phi$ is a surjection, how the map $g$ is defined ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\mathcal F$ is a line bundle, that $f_* \mathcal F$ is locally free, and that $f^* f_* \mathcal F \to \mathcal F$ is surjective.  Then to each point $x \in X$ we have a hyperplane $H_x\subset \kappa(x)\otimes_{\kappa(y)} (f_*\mathcal F)_y$ (this is the fibre at $x$
of the pull-back via $f$ of $f_*\mathcal F$; here $y := f(x)$), defined to be the kernel of the induced surjection
$$\kappa(x)\otimes_{\kappa(y)} (f_*\mathcal F)_y \to \mathcal F_x$$
The map $g$ is then defined via
$x \mapsto H_x.$

Comment: Thank You for your detailed explanation, it takes me some time to understand though. BTW, what reference may contains this argument ? Thanks again

Comment: @Shuhang: I think you should try to understand what's happening in the case when $X$ is a projective variety over the field $k$ and $Y = $ Spec $k$.  In this case $f_*\mathcal F$ is just $H^0(X,\mathcal F)$, and is automatically a finite dimensional $k$-vector space, and the assumption that it is gen'd by global sections is equivalent to assuming that the  complete linear series of Cartier divisors associated to $\mathcal L$ is base-point free.   The morphism $g$ is then the projective morphism associated to this complete linear series.

Comment: @Shuhang: The study of linear series of divisors and the projective morphisms they give rise to is a big subject, and it makes sense to begin with simple examples, such as taking $X = \mathbb P^n$ and $\mathcal F = \mathcal O(d)$ (for $d > 0$), in which case your morphism $g$ is the $d$-uple embedding of $X$.    Or if you take $X$ to be an elliptic curve with origin $O$, and take $\mathcal F = \mathcal O(2D)$, then the morphism $g$ is the usual degree two projection of $X$ onto $\mathbb P^1$.

Comment: @Shuhang: The general theory (at least in this case when $Y = $ Spec $k$) is  discussed in Hartshorne Ch. II, section 7, I think.  (And in many other places, too.  Googling "linear series'' and "projective embedding'' may help you get started.)